# Jsp attribute DISABLE by condition

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, jsp-tags

On this time I have a list of objects Product with attributes name, a list of Category and quantity.

In my jsp tag i have the following select:

```
<select name="quantity" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

This select is used to change de product quantity and send the new value to the back end.
But I have one case where i need to disable the select

```
<select name="quantity" onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled="true">
```

How can I enable or disable the select depending on the category string value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Jquery, you can do this to disable a select. I added an id to make it easier.

add id attribute:

```
<select name="quantity" id="quantity" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

disable via jquery:

```
$('#quantity').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

You can also disable it via JSTL if you're using that. Previous answer mentions choose,when,otherwise tags but something like this can be done with just a simple **if** tag.

if quantity request variable set by servlet is empty

```
<c:if test="${empty quantityVar}">
<select name="quantity" onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled="true">
</c:if>
```

if quantity request variable set by servlet is not empty

```
<c:if test="${not empty quantityVar}">
<select name="quantity" onchange="this.form.submit()">
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSTL core  tag `<c:choose>`.

The `<c: choose>` works like a Java switch statement in that it lets you choose between a number of alternatives. Where the switch statement has case statements, the `<c:choose>` tag has `<c:when>` tags. Just as a switch statement has the default clause to specify a default action, `<c:choose>` has `<c:otherwise>` as the default clause.

Example:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<html>
   <head>
      <title><c:choose> Tag Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <c:set var = "salary" scope = "session" value = "${2000*2}"/>
      <p>Your salary is : <c:out value = "${salary}"/></p>
      <c:choose>

         <c:when test = "${salary <= 0}">
            Salary is very low to survive.
         </c:when>

         <c:when test = "${salary > 1000}">
            Salary is very good.
         </c:when>

         <c:otherwise>
            No comment sir...
         </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi! your commet was really helpfull too.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a function in JS that disables the second select depending on what your first select outcome is.

It may be best to start with some basics from the following link:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_select_disabled